# HTML 5 Web Storage - Local/server communication

Tags: ajax, html, local-storage, web-storage

I need load localStorage data right on my homepage. But when the page loads, the PHP/SQL instructions are already processed.
There's a way to process it before the server interation and use the localStorage data in my SQL instructions?

ps. I tried AJAX, loading my homepage in a DIV inside an index page... but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no - you can't read the LocalStorage data on the *first* load of your web site. However, you can use Ajax to hit your server and send a copy of any LocalStorage value to your server. You mentioned using ajax to load your homepage in a div. That *should* work, if you pass along the LocalStorage information in the url. So for example, imagine you have a localstorage key called name. If you want to load the contents of foo.php into a div and have PHP get access to name, you would pass it in the URL: "foo.php?name="+escape(localstorage.name)". You can also use a Form post too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It worked, I've passed the values in the URL as you said.
You, sir, deserve my respect. I declare you Lord of the Webz.
haha just kidding, thank you, really.

Comment: Lord of the Webz - I'll take that. ;)